# DataTables.Net - Is there a way to set a property from the data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

What i'd like to do is set the "column" property from the ajax data

the json data has a "data" and "columns" property, so to pull the data i'd have something like this.

```
primaryTable = $('#example').DataTable({
            "ajax": "data.txt"
        });
```

lets say that txt file has a column property that would define the column {"data":"Name"} etc, is there a way i can reference it?

```
primaryTable = $('#example').DataTable({
            "ajax": "data.txt"
            "columns" : data.columns
        });
```

is there some way to reference it?
The other way would be to use the jQuery.ajax or getJSON, which i've played around with and couldnt figure out how to get the data to load correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that (at least as of November 2013), it was not possible to be done using a single AJAX call. [Source](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/18367/can-i-set-the-table-column-names-dynamically-by-getting-them-from-ajax)

> The answer is no - I'm sorry to say you cannot do that in DataTables at this time. The full range of options that are available in aoColumns cannot be represented in JSON (specifically functions) so there is no method for this in DataTables at this time. I might relax that in future, but at the moment you'll need to make an Ajax request to get the column information yourself. Allan

You could solve the issue by issuing two consecutive AJAX calls: first for fetching data to populate table header columns, and the second - for the data itself.

The link provides a sample call as well.